# Magento 2 API testing

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, api-functional-tests

I have created an API and I want to write test files for that API. How can it be done in Magento 2.3.5? I have referred the link - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/web-api-functional-testing.html and also saw the video by a famous Russian Magento Developer. I am unable to run the tests and this is the error I am getting if I run the test.

The command I ran from my Magento root directory is

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --config dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml
```

The error is:

> #### *Could not read "dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml".*

Also, in PHPStorm, I am unable to configure the Unit Test version. I am getting this error.

[image: phpunit.phar error]

If I use the autoloader.php I am getting the following error:

[image: Composer Auto Loader error]

When I run the following command I am getting this error.

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit app/code/<Directory>
```

[image: Command Error]

I need help in setting up the API testing in PHPStorm and the correct working code to test a POST API

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to test api, use postman application to test api much easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**
Verifiy PHP SOAP extension is installed
—> at the top of index.php that is used to serve the Magento site, replace the first line `<?php` by `<?php phpinfo(); die();`
And refresh the site, check PHH_SOAP extension appears as per the screenshot below

[image]

**Step 2:** as per devdocs documentation
Copy /dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml.dist and phpunit_soap.xml.dist to /dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml and phpunit_soap.xml.

**Step 3:** create an API user
Go to `System/Integration`, add an API user and assign all the roles (at least initially until the first call is made)

Validate the above steps by running a default Magento API call in Postman for isntance. Or using a php script like the one below (the bearer line has to be adjusted with `your token access key`)

```
<?php

// \Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata::getServicesConfig to debug the available webapi services
$params = ['order_id' => null];
foreach ($argv as $arg) {
    if (preg_match("%^--(.*?)=(.*?)$%", $arg, $m)) {
        $params[$m[1]] = $m[2];
    }
}

if (!$params['order_id'])
    exit("Specify order id (as --order_id=_ID_ parameter)\n");

$orderId   = (int)$params['order_id'];
$url = 'http://magecertif.test/index.php/rest/V1/orders/' . $orderId;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer 75koeeydi18xzclhmdib8ou65h9qk8cx' // this is the access token for the API user
    )
);

//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

the result of this script should be like the screenshot below:

[image]

**Step 4:**

```
Copy /dev/tests/api-functional/config/install-config-mysql.php.dist to /dev/tests/api-functional/config/install-config-mysql.php.
```

replace your database details and host with your system details.

**Step 5:**
Finally to setup PHPStorm, if your xdebug setup works for general web page browsing, then the command-line for the webapi key should be working:

for me, I had the same error as you initially. I have to change the command-line

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --config dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml
```

with

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --config /data/macbook/mage-cert2/dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml
```

And then, my API ran eventually, see result in screenshot below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I did everything as you instructed. When I click on the run icon, I got the same error that said that the PHPUNIT version is not specified. But the console provided a command, so I copied that and replaced the phpunit with the one given by Magento.

Comment: The test ran successfully, and I was even able to fwrite the response. Kudos to that, but it would be helpful if you know how to clear the PHPUNIT version not found error in the PHPSTORM.

Comment: We need to have some steps: you accept the answer so that we are all clear with the question as it was when I answered it. Then I can help giving you pointers on this part after this

Comment: Answer Accepted.

Comment: My answer has a different path for phpunit than in your question. Also, my path matches devdocs path. So why can’t you use same path as devdocs? And what version of Magento do you use?

Comment: Yes, I know that the path for PHPUNIT is different as you use Mac and I use Linux. I use Magento 2.3.5-p1.